# Restful webservice with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, rest

I want to create a webservice in my web application for selecting, deleting, adding and updating the records into the database. I use Hibernate as the backend layer.

How can I create a Restful webservice around my existing webapp so that the services such as create account, delete account, show user accounts, etc can be done using webservice from outside world?

Can somebody provide me a link or tutorial to create a Restful webservice with the hibernate as a backend layer?

Answer (score 0):

REST is like the interface between your web layer and your application layer. Hibernate is the interface between your application layer and your database layer. They are unrelated and should have no communication between each other.

Your application layer should contain simple Java Bean-like models that would easily be converted to the front end (as JSON or XML) or to the database (having Hibernate map to your DB).